# Using html() method with a symbol in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to create an updates list, when you see only the title of the update- unless you click on a down-pointing triangle near the title, and then you will see the full update information + the down-pointing triangle will change to an up-pointing triangle. And after clicking on the up-pointing triangle- you will see only the title of the update again + the triangle will be down-pointing.

So I wrote the following code in order to implement that:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    arrowsUpdate(); 
</script>


<p>
<span class="down-arrow">&#9660;</span> 
<br>
<span class="hidden-text">update 1</span>
</p>

<p>
<span class="down-arrow">&#9660;</span>
<br> 
<span class="hidden-text">update 2</span>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function arrowsUpdate(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".down-arrow").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $(this).siblings(".hidden-text").slideToggle(0,"linear"); 
                if($(this).html()=="&#9660;")
                    $(this).html("&#9650;");
                else
                    $(this).html("&#9660;");             
            });        
        }); 
    });
}
```

The problem with this code is that the pointing triangle is always down-pointing. It seems that there is a problem with the `if` statement- which always returns false.
I don't understand why that happens, especially when the set code lines  (`$(this).html("&#9650;");`and `$(this).html("&#9660;");`) are working as expected (tried using those code lines in a different page- and it works).

**Why the condition `$(this).html()=="&#9660;"` returns always false, if the content of `this` is `&#9660;`?**

Comment: @Jonathan If it's always returning false, changing from `==` to `===` won't help. `===` is **more** discriminating, not less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set html with entities, but when you get it back, it will no longer be entities but characters, that's how entities work.

To be clearer, this line fails every time

```
if( $(this).html()=="&#9660;" )
```

because `$(this).html()` will never return an entity, but the character `▼` instead, proof ...

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
console.log( document.body.innerHTML )
```

An easier way to create toggle functionality without relying on the markup, would be to just use a flag

```
function arrowsUpdate() {
  $(".down-arrow").on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".hidden-text").slideToggle(0, "linear");

    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(this).html(flag ? "&#9660;" : "&#9650;").data('flag', !flag);
  });
}
```